# How can I turn a stock HTC One into a Google Experience one?

Tags: htc-one, google-experience

I'm considering buying an HTC One soon. Sadly, the Google Experience one isn't available in my country in the Play store. Either way, I would get the new phone from my carrier anyway.

So I'm wondering, can I turn my phone into a proper Google Experience version? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This how-to](http://htc-one.wonderhowto.com/how-to/turn-your-htc-one-into-real-htc-one-google-play-edition-0147731/) meticulously explains how to flash a ROM taken from the Google Play edition of the One. To summarize:

- **Backup your data**
- [Root your One](http://htc-one.wonderhowto.com/how-to/unlock-your-bootloader-root-your-htc-one-install-custom-recovery-using-twrp-0147357/)
- Download the [ROM](http://goo.im/devs/bigxie/m7/bigxie_m7_GPe_odexed_tbalden.zip)
- Boot into TWRP, wipe the old ROM and install the new one

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [MoDaCo.SWITCH project](http://www.modaco.com/topic/363797-beta-11-modacoswitch-htc-one-support-topic/), which allows you to dual-boot both HTC One Sense, and the Google Experience. You can share app data between the two, so you don't have to maintain 2 sets of apps in either environment, and you can switch back and forth anytime.

If you like the Google Experience better, then you can just stick with it. You'll supposedly get all the regular updates from Google.

It's still in Beta, but it's been under active development, and has come pretty far.

Installation instructions are at the link above, but it's basically the same process as installing a regular ROM, which can be a bit tricky if you're not technically-minded.

Hope that helps.